# Upsert of Vertices and Edge in a single Traversal in Gremlin

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I've been trying for several hours to write a gremlin statement to handle upserting 2 vertices and 1 edge between them, without much luck.

in pseudo-gremlin what I want to do is pretty straightforward and is the following:

```
g.V()
.hasLabel("person")
.has("custom_id", "123")
.fold()
.coalesce(
  __.unfold().property(single, "name", "Tom"), 
  __.addV("person").property(single, "custom_id", "123").property(single, "name", "Tom"))
.as("fromStep")
.V()
.hasLabel("person")
.has("custom_id", "654")
.fold()
.coalesce(
  __.unfold().property(single, "name", "Sally"),
  __.addV("person").property(single, "custom_id", "654").property(single, "name", "Sally"))
.as("toStep")
.E()
.hasLabel("knows")
.where(__.inV().is("fromStep"))
.where(__.outV().is("toStep"))
.fold()
.coalesce(
  __.unfold().property("since", "2020-01-01"),
  __.addE("knows").property("since", "2020-01-01").from("fromStep").to("toStep")
```

The problem with this code is that each `fold` step, being a barrier step "removes" the value of the previous `as` steps.

Is there a way to do this properly in a single statement?

### **SOLUTION**

Thanks to Kelvin answer's here's the solution :)

```
g.V()
.hasLabel("person")
.has("custom_id", "123")
.fold()
.coalesce(
    __.unfold().property(single, "name", "Tom"), 
    __.addV("person").property(single, "custom_id", "123").property(single, "name", "Tom"))
.store("a")
.V()
.hasLabel("person")
.has("custom_id", "654")
.fold()
.coalesce(
    __.unfold().property(single, "name", "Sally"),
    __.addV("person").property(single, "custom_id", "654").property(single, "name", "Sally"))
.store("b")
.fold()
.select("a").unfold().as("from")
.select("b").unfold().coalesce(
    __.inE("knows").where(__.outV().as("from")).property("since", "2020-01-01"),
    __.addE("knows").property("since", "2020-01-01").from("from")
)
```

Comment: Are you able to provide custom IDs for each vertex in your use case? If yes then you can use those IDs later in the query.

Comment: That might help if I'm inserting new vertices, but how does it help if I'm updating them, I'd still need to find the old ids. but to answer your question is yes, I can provide my own :)

Comment: I provided an example as an answer below of one way to work around the reducing barrier behavior w.r.t. traversal labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, labels applied using an `as` step are lost after a barrier/map step like `fold` is used. However, `store` and `aggregate` bulk sets will survive intact. Here is a simple pattern that works after a `fold` that you should be able to adapt for your use case. As we discussed in the comments, if you knew the ID of the vertices you were searching for and if the ID was not found you created it that would give you another way to approach this. Anyway, here is one way that works in the presence of a `fold` step.

```
gremlin> g.V('3').store('a').
......1>   V('4').store('b').
......2>   fold().
......3>   select('a').unfold().as('from').
......4>   select('b').unfold().as('to').
......5>   addE('test').
......6>     from('from').
......7>     to('to')    

==>e[60876][3-test->4]
```

One other note, in general mid traversal `E` steps are not supported. It really should be written as `V().outE()`

Comment: Exactly what I needed :) I'll update my original question with the solution, thanks a lot!